# git diff --cached: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous

Tags: git

i use git diff --cached command then i got warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.

now if i used git branch i am getting Error like that

```
error: refs/description points nowhere!
error: refs/index points nowhere!
error: refs/packed-refs points nowhere!
error: refs/config points nowhere!
  205010_v2
```

Comment: Are you by any chance in a newly created repository? That is before making any commit at all?

Comment: That's weird. Those files live in `.git`, not `.git/refs`. Can you say what version of git you have, how you created the repository and what you did there?

Comment: Do not pass go.  `git fsck --full` now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the top-level files in your `.git` directory (or another `.git` directory) were somehow copied to `.git/refs`.

The ambiguous ref name warning is probably because there is both `.git/HEAD` and `.git/refs/HEAD`.  If both files exist, the name `HEAD` could refer to either file, hence the warning.  It's a warning and not an error because Git will always choose `.git/HEAD` over `.git/refs/HEAD`.  See `git help revisions` for documentation on how Git resolves reference names.

The "points nowhere" errors are from non-reference files in the `.git/refs` directory.

To fix, delete the following files after backing them up:

- `.git/refs/HEAD`
- `.git/refs/description`
- `.git/refs/index`
- `.git/refs/packed-refs`
- `.git/refs/config`